# Hide own implicit Intent from share list

Tags: android, android-intent

The Twitter Android App has (at least) two intent-filters. One for tweeting and one for direct messages.

When you want to share something via twitter (from another app) you usually see both items listed in the implicit intent list (as in the first image below).

[image: Sharing to Twitter from another app, e.g. Chrome]

When you want to share something from the twitter app, you get the same intent, but with only one option (to direct message). The other options is somehow removed. See the second image for reference.

[image: Sharing from Twitter]

My questions is, how does the Twitter app do this?

I believe they query the apps that can handle the content and remove their own intent (Tweet) from there and show the results in a custom BottomSheet. I believe this is the case, because the exit Animation of the BottomSheet is a bit different than the standard Share BottomSheet animation of other apps.

If it is not custom, is there another way to filter your own intents in your own app?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for sharing through apps which you want to show in dialog

```
public void onShareClick(View v){
List<Intent> targetShareIntents=new ArrayList<Intent>();
Intent shareIntent=new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
List<ResolveInfo> resInfos=getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
if(!resInfos.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("Have package");
    for(ResolveInfo resInfo : resInfos){
        String packageName=resInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        Log.i("Package Name", packageName);
        if(packageName.contains("com.twitter.android") || packageName.contains("com.facebook.katana") || packageName.contains("com.kakao.story")){
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, resInfo.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            targetShareIntents.add(intent);
        }
    }
    if(!targetShareIntents.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Have Intent");
        Intent chooserIntent=Intent.createChooser(targetShareIntents.remove(0), "Choose app to share");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Do not Have Intent");
        showDialaog(this);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but that does not answer the question. I know of this way, and I know that I can filter manually, but my question is whether there is some other way or does Twitter do it like this as well.

Comment: there might be other ways but i think twitter guys are doing manually.

Comment: What are the other ways you know of? Why do you think Twitter is doing it manually?

Comment: What else they can use? I think they are also doing it manually.. Please upvote my answer if it helped u a bit. Thanks